# Twilio - Interrupt a Say Block

Tags: twilio

I have a Play block, that Says many .mp3 files (it reads an account balance and other information about an account.

The result is a a message that takes a while to listen to. The messages vary in length, depending what is said.

I'd like 'any' key to end playing the messages and skip back to the c#.

I tried using a Gather, but the timeout value either truncates the Say block, or waits for ages at the end (if no key pressed)

Any thought on how to achieve this?

The current flow is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
    <Play>/Voice/test/messages/CurrentlyYourPAYGBalanceIs_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/78.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/currency/_pounds_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/_and_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/91.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/currency/Pence.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/messages/_AndYouHavea_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/products/BD021.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/_with_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/95.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/messages/_VoiceBalance.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/_and_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/2.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/data/_gigabytes_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/200.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/_and_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/numbers/94.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/data/_megabytes_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/_remaining.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/misc/Expiring_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/dates/31.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/months/_of12_.mp3</Play>
    <Play>/Voice/test/common/years/2016.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Comment: Hi David, can you post the exact flow of your twiml?

Comment: Megan, I have posted the current flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David, check out this question:

[Twilio play pause/resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19880217/twilio-play-pause-resume)

Specifically:

> The playback is interrupt-able as it is wrapped in `Gather` which points
>   to `Pause` action.

You can wrap your `<Play>` [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) in a [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) and point to a URL containing the instructions you wish.